# Die-rolling Hamiltonian cycles

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry, open-problems, recreational-mathematics

Let $R$ be a rectangular region of the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$,
each of whose unit squares is labeled with a number
in $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \rbrace$.
Say that such a labeled $R$ is *die-rolling Hamiltonian*,
or simply *rollable*,
if there is a Hamiltonian cycle obtained by rolling a unit die
cube over its edges so that, for each square $s \in R$,
the cube lands on $s$ precisely once, and when it does so,
the top face of the cube matches the number in $s$.
For example, the $4 \times 4$ "board" shown below
is rollable.

     
[image: Dice Rolling]

> **Q**. Is it true that, if $R$ is die-rolling Hamiltonian, then the
> Hamiltonian cycle is unique, i.e., there are never two distinct
> die-rolling Hamiltonian cycles on $R$?

This "unique-rollability"
question arose out of a problem I posed in 2005, and was largely
solved two years later, in a paper entitled,
"On rolling cube puzzles" (complete citation below;
the $4 \times 4$ example above is from Fig. 17 of that paper).
Although the original question involved computational complexity,
the possible uniqueness of Hamiltonian cycles is independent
of those computational issues, so I thought it might be useful
to expose it to a different community, who might bring
different tools to bear.
It is known to hold for $R$ with side lengths at most 8.
If not every cell of $R$ is labeled, and unlabeled cells are forbidden
to the die, then there are examples with more than one Hamiltonian cycle.

**Edit1**. Rolling a regular tetrahedron on the equilateral triangular (hexagonal) lattice
is not as interesting.  See the Trigg article cited below.

**Edit2**.
Serendipitously, *gordon-royle* posted a perhaps(?) relevantly related
question:
"[Uniquely Hamiltonian graphs with minimum degree 4](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87496/)."

---

- The computational version is

  [Open Problem 68](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/P68.html#Problem.68) at
  [The Open Problems Project](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/TOPP/).
- "On rolling cube puzzles."
  Buchin, Buchin, Demaine, Demaine, El-Khechen, Fekete, Knauer, Schulz, Taslakian.
  *Proceedings of the 19th Canadian Conference on Computational Geometry*, Pages 141–144, 2007.
  [PDF download.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/schulz/papers/RollingFull.pdf)
- Charles W. Trigg. "Tetrahedron rolled onto a plane." *J. Recreational Mathematics*, 3(2):82–87, 1970.

Comment: Your template is of a left-handed die, while your rollable board is for a right-handed die, and cannot be rolled with a lefty die.

Comment: Sharp eye, Michael!. Just replaced the Latin-cross unfolding with right-handed die.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see.  My original template needed to be folded toward the viewer; the new one away from the viewer, which is more natural. 

Comment: Wouldn't problem 68 in TOPP need an update? Marzio's paper seems to settle the question.

Comment: @domotorp: Good point. Will attend to that when time permits.

Comment: I am looking for the book from @Joseph O'Rourke comment "**Charles W. Trigg. "Tetrahedron rolled onto a plane." J. Recreational Mathematics, 3(2):82–87, 1970**." However, I did not see anywhere from the Internet.
Can anyone please share the information of the book? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE: I played around and came up with a construction (chance of containing a mistake is high!), below it I leave my original answer for explanation.

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
3&-&2& &2&-&1&-&5&-&6& &5&-&1&-&2&-&6&-&5&-&1&-&2\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & &|\cr
1& &1& &3& &4&-&5&-&3& &4& &1&-&4&-&6&-&3&-&1&-&4\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & \cr
4& &5& &5& &1&-&5&-&6&-&2& &5&-&4&-&2&-&3&-&5&-&4\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &|\cr
6& &6&-&4& &6&-&3&-&1&-&4&-&6&-&3&-&1&-&4&-&6& &6\cr
|& & & & & &|& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &|& &|\cr
3& &2&-&4&-&5& &4&-&2& &5&-&6&-&2& &2&-&4& &5& &3\cr
|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& &|& & & &|& &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
1& &1& &1&-&5&-&6& &6& &3&-&6& &3&-&1& &1& &1& &1\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& & & &|& & & & & &|& &|& &|\cr
4& &5& &3& &2&-&3& &5&-&3&-&2& &3&-&5& &3& &2& &4\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & & & &|& &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
6& &6& &6& &6& &6&-&5&-&1&-&2&-&6& &6& &6& &6& &6\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
3&-&2&-&4&-&5&-&3&-&2&-&4&-&5&-&3&-&2&-&4&-&5&-&3\cr
|& & & & & & & &|& & & & & & & &|& & & & & & & &|\cr
1&-&2&-&6&-&5&-&1&-&2&-&6&-&5&-&1&-&2&-&6&-&5&-&1\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
4& &4& &4& &4& &4&-&5&-&3&-&2&-&4& &4& &4& &4& &4\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & & & &|& &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
6& &5& &1& &2&-&1& &5&-&1&-&2& &1&-&5& &1& &2& &6\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& & & &|& & & & & &|& &|& &|\cr
3& &3& &3&-&5&-&4& &4& &1&-&4& &1&-&3& &3& &3& &3\cr
|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& &|& & & &|& &|& &|& &|& &|\cr
1& &2&-&6&-&5& &6&-&2& &5&-&4&-&2& &2&-&6& &5& &1\cr
|& & & & & &|& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &|& &|\cr
4& &4&-&6& &4&-&1&-&3&-&6&-&4&-&1&-&3&-&6&-&4& &4\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &|\cr
6& &5& &4& &3&-&5&-&4&-&2& &5&-&6&-&2&-&1&-&5&-&6\cr
|& &|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & \cr
3& &3& &1& &6&-&5&-&1& &6& &3&-&6&-&4&-&1&-&3&-&6\cr
|& &|& &|& & & & & &|& &|& & & & & & & & & & & &|\cr
1&-&2& &2&-&3&-&5&-&4& &5&-&3&-&2&-&4&-&5&-&3&-&2
\end{array}$

HOW THIS THING WORKS:

I think there are configurations that are not uniquely Hamiltonian. The example I have in mind should be around 14 times 14, except that I do not have a definite example, but I hope I can convince you that only a technical difficulty is missing.

Our goal is to prove a somewhat stronger statement, to exhibit an R that has two different die-rolling H-cycles in which the cube is in the same position over every field no matter which H-cycle you take. This allows us to define a nice graph on R. First we will give one H-cycle, then add the edges not contained in this H-cycle along which the cube could move, only allowing moves that take the cube into the same position over the field as it would have in the H-cycle. Denote the obtained graph by G. It is easy to see that G is a subgraph of the grid-graph, moreover, G cannot have cycles whose length is less than 10 and G has (at least) two H-cycles.

One such graph is given below on the 13 times 10 grid (130 vertices). Legend: X marks the squares contained in both H-cycles, while 1 and resp. 2 the squares contained in only one of them.

$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc} %   
X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X\cr
X& & & & & & & & & & & &X\cr
X& &X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X& &X\cr
X& &X& & & & & & & &X& &X\cr
1&1&1&1&X&X&X&X&X&2&2&2&2\cr
X& &X& & & & & & & &X& &X\cr
X& &X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X& &X\cr
X& & & & & & & & & & & &X\cr
X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X&X\
\end{array}
$

Unfortunately this graph is not yet good enough, we cannot give a good numbering of R to make the edges valid. However, we can play around (i.e. make more wiggly using more area) with the top and bottom parts (shared by both H-cycles) and I am sure that way we can ensure the validity of all edges. This is the only missing part which seems to be only technical.

Comment: Wow!! $\mbox{}$

Comment: Page 17 of the cited paper says, "It remains open whether nonuniqueness of Hamiltonian cycles holds for fully labeled boards."
If your example holds up, you have settled that question---Congrats!

Comment: this is really an amazing answer

Answer (score 3):

While browsing the recreational-mathematics tag I noticed this old question again.

In 2012 I published on my blog a draft paper in which I give another example of a (bigger) board with two distinct Hamiltonian cycles (but domotorp was quicker to answer).

In the paper I also prove that the *Rolling Cube Puzzle in labeled boards without free cells and with blocked cells is NP-complete* (an open problem).

http://www.nearly42.org/cstheory/rolling-a-cube-can-be-tricky/

... I never had the time to clean it up and submit it to a journal for a serious review (though I tested the gadgets with Mathematica).

If someone wants to give it a look ...