# A conjecture about Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph which is a cycle $C$ equipped with some chords such that $\delta (G)\geq 3$. In other words, every vertex of $C$ is adjacent with at least one of the chords.

I conjecture that there must exist at least one Hamiltonian cycle in $G$ besides $C$. Can you prove it or give a counterexample?

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.21729/abstract Abstract We construct an infinite family of uniquely hamiltonian graphs of minimum degree 4, maximum degree 14, and of arbitrarily high maximum degree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think Gordon Royle and Joseph O'Rourke answer it [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87496/uniquely-hamiltonian-graphs-with-minimum-degree-4)

> A graph is uniquely hamiltonian if it has exactly one Hamilton cycle
>
> Apparently, however, there are uniquely hamiltonian graphs with minimum degree equal to four - the latest edition of Bondy & Murty's Graph Theory even gives a reference to a paper by H. Fleischner entitled "Uniquely hamiltonian graphs of minimum degree 4", To Appear, Journal of Graph Theory and dates it at 2007.

Since the graph have a hamiltonian cycle you can consider it
a cycle $C$ and all the edges not in $C$ are chords.

Searching the web for "uniquely hamiltonian graph" returns references.

**Added**

Explicit counterexample from [this paper p. 13](http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/20/ocr-ajc-v20-p111.pdf)

[image]

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.21729/abstract 
Abstract We construct an infinite family of uniquely hamiltonian graphs of minimum degree 4, maximum degree 14, and of arbitrarily high maximum degree.

Comment: Fleischner's paper has been available online since 31 Jan 2013 at the J. Graph Theory website to those with a paid subscription. I expect it should be officially published pretty soon. Note that in his concluding section, Fleischner conjectures that there do not exist any 4-connected uniquely Hamiltonian graphs.

Comment: joro,Thank you very much!Your answer is very helpful!!!

Comment: @user40096 You are welcome.

Comment: Dear joro,as what I said in the question above,Let G be a simple graph which is a cycle $C$ equipped with some chords such that $\delta (G)\geq 3$,in other words,every vertex of $C$ is adjacent with at least one of the chords.If I let the length of every edge of the cycle $C$ is $1$ and the length of every chord of $C$ is $2$(subdivide each chord with a vertex),can I get a cycle in $G$ which is longer than $C$?