# Paper "Tetrahedron rolled onto a plane"

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, paper-request

I am looking for the article Charles W. Trigg, "Tetrahedron rolled onto a plane", *J. Recreational Mathematics*, 3(2):82–87, 1970.

It is from @Joseph O'Rourke comment in the previous post "[Die-rolling Hamiltonian cycles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87437/die-rolling-hamiltonian-cycles/334408#334408)"

However, I did not see that book anywhere from the Internet. Can anyone please share the information of the book?

Thanks.

Comment: You are seeking not a book, but rather one 6-page article from vol.3 of the *Journal of Recreational Mathematics.* The article is from 1970, well before there were regular electronic versions. This may help: [Table of Contents Pages from All 38 Volumes of Journal of Recreational Mathematics](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/table-of-contents-pages-from-all-38-volumes-of-journal-of-recreational-mathematics). I think your best route is what we call in the US "Interlibrary Loan."

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Thanks so much for the useful information.